# prevent redirection to my homepage before user logs in using facebook login api?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook

I am using the Facebook Javascript SDK to allow users to login to my website.I am using ASP.NET along with javascript. I want users to login via facebook and then I create a session variable with that userid. Then I want the user to navigate to homepage. 
The problem is whenever I goto login page, it automatically redirects to homepage without even letting me login. Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Below is my login code:

Login page:
login.aspx:

`<%@ Page Language="C#" %>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>FB Login Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
            status: true, 
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true  
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                <%Session["userid"] = "' + uid + '"; %>
                <% if(Session["userid"] != null)
                   Response.Redirect("myhomepage.aspx"); %>

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                FB.login();
            } else {
                FB.login();
            }
        });
    };

    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

</script>
<h4>Login using your Facebook account: </h4><br />
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A quick look (only) at your code shows that you are creating and setting a `Session` object and it will never be `null` - your redirect will always fire. Check the value of `uid` first before assigning it..hth

Comment: Yes i agree to you. But shouldn't it fire only when the response.status==connected is true? and response.status is true only when user logs in. But it doesn't allow me to login at all.

Comment: I haven't toyed with FB login (yet), so my initial _guess_ is that, are you (already logged in/have some sort of login cookie already set in your browser/client)? _Typically_ these external login providers will check for an _already logged in user_ before having to request yet-another-login flow (unnecessary).

Comment: Yes I am logged out of facebook. and then i tried doing this. I am not able to understand why the flow is going to the code which is only used when I login.